# how to write oledb connection string for oracle8i(in a remote machine)

Tags: oracle, oledb

How to write oledb connection string for oracle8i(in a remote machine)?

I mean the iis is setup in my machine(the win7 system),but the oracle8i is installed in another win xp system,how to write the connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st, the remote machine certainly needs an oracle client installed.

2nd, if you're unsure about the correct syntax try creating an empty *.udl file (0 byte) and double click it. This will open a dialog which lets you configure and test the connection. After that you've got the connection string inside the *.udl file.

Comment: So do you mean I have to install the oracle client in the machine(iis installed machine)? It is said that using the ole connection does not need the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should get something [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle)